# jquery pause before displaying next step

Tags: javascript, jquery, delay, pause

On button next click (Game context), I want to make pause to show correct answer before showing next question. how can I do it?
I try this :

```
showCorrectAnswer();
questionCounter++;
setTimeout(displayNext(), 6000);
/* Or */
showCorrectAnswer();
questionCounter++;
wait(6000);
displayNext();

/*with wait*/
function wait(ms){
    var start = new Date().getTime();
    var end = start;
    while(end < start + ms) {
        end = new Date().getTime();
    }
}
```

But does not work.
Thanks

Comment: No error. When user select his answer and click "next", the next is shown automatically. no time for user to see the correct answer. I want to show him, his answer in yellow and the correct answer in red with explanations for 6 seconds before showing the next question.

Comment: JavaScript can be confusing at times, If you're interested in how to do it in jQuery, @Panos's answer is what you're looking for, as `delay()` is the jQuery wrapper for `setTimeout()` and... just works. If you want to understand why it didn't work, I hope my answer is clear enough.

Comment: Thanks, your answer is clear and helps me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are supposed to pass either an anonymous function to `setTimeout()` (in which you place what you want to execute when the timeout expires) or the name of a defined function. If you place `()` after the name, as you did, the function is executed when the `setTimeout()` is parsed, not when it expires, expecting the result of running your function to return another function that will be executed when the `setTimeout()` expires - much like the anonymous function does.

Either of the following will work as expected. Name of function:

```js
showCorrectAnswer();
questionCounter++;
setTimeout(displayNext, 6000);
```

...or anonymous wrapper:

```js
showCorrectAnswer();
questionCounter++;
setTimeout(function(){
  displayNext();
}, 6000);
```

In most real life scenarios, it is advisable to change `questionCounter` value inside the `displaynNext()` function, not before.

Answer (score 1):

With jquery you can use:

`$('.container').hide().delay(6000).fadeIn(displayNext());`

Comment: There are three problems with your solution. **1.** You are not explaining anything, like you don't know how or why it works. While sometimes useful, such answers are generally regarded as low quality on [so]. See [answer] for details. **2.** You are assuming there is a `.container` that's holding the questions. What if it's not? What if it's also containing things that shouldn't be faded in/out? **3.** Your solution displays the next question after `6400ms`, because the default duration of `fadeIn` is `400ms`. So you should change `6000` to `5600`.

Comment: Andrei I'm on the road, mobile version of stack ;)

Answer (score 0):

check out this

you have done a small mistake `setTimeout(displayNext(),6000)` which calls immediately instead you should only pass function name. `setTimeout(displayNext,6000)`

If you want to do call with parameters make sure you write as a function and then put all your code inside it `setTimeout(function(){displayNext(parameter1,parameter2);},6000)`

```js
function displayNext(){
alert("display");
}
```

```html
<input type="number" step="1000" id="num_milisecond" value=1000> milliseconds
<input type="button" onclick="setTimeout(displayNext, document.getElementById('num_milisecond').value);" value="click to allert">
```